# Assigning static IPs to VoIP phones in packet tracer

Tags: dhcp, packet-tracer, cisco-voip

Is there a way to assign IPs and dn to VoIP phones in a network configuration without using DHCP?
Such that if I have PCs and VoIP phones connected to the same switch, which is connected to a router and I configure DHCP server for the PCs alone on the router, the server does not assign IPs to the VoIP phones as well.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign static IPs to the phones by logging in and configuring the phones directly.  DN's are assigned by the call manager when the phone registers with it.